How do I combine two arrays when I have a custom title
={"Title1"; A2:A} would set a custom title and then return from the second row in the specified column, but how can I continue this one for the next column? ={"Title1"; A2:A, "Title2"; B2:B} only returns the second column and skips the first one.


You may try:
={{"Title1"; A2:A}, {"Title2"; B2:B}}

OR
=hstack(vstack("Title1",A2:A), vstack("Title2",B2:B))


or:
={{"Title1", "Title2"}; A2:B}

but you can use also:
=HSTACK(VSTACK("Title1"; A2:A); VSTACK("Title2"; B2:B))

or:
=VSTACK(SPLIT("Title1×Title2"; "×"); A2:B)

